# Can run code with react native and expo, but cannot build apk with gradle assembleRelease

Tags: react-native, gradle

error : cannot determine java version 10.0.2

using latest android studio 3.1.3 and react native 0.56

Ive already built the key and copy the key to android/app folder as described.

when tried to run gradleW assembleReleased command, it has following error :

"cannot determine java version 10.0.2"

Comment: Show your build.gradle

Comment: It seems to be the problem with your java version. Try to uninstall java 10 and re-install Java Version 8 and try. If you want more info let me know for full answer

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:78)
        at

Comment: org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)

Comment: downgrading to java 8 , now doing npm rm -rf node_modules/; yarn cache clean; yarn